# Using reflection, how do I detect properties that have setters?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this code to loop through an object and get all of its properties through reflection:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(TBase).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var oldValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(oldVersion, null);
}
```

How can I do a check to only look at properties that have a "Set" on them? (I want to ignore read-only values - just "Get".)

Comment: Don't forget about properties with private, protected, internal, or internal protected setters....those trouble-makers.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice may you explain me why this is necessary? (especially the private ones) I mean is it even possible to access private fields and properties due to reflection? - Wohh.. looked it up.. it is possible. i didn't say anything.

Answer (score 124):

`PropertyInfo.CanWrite` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite.aspx))

or

`PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ef4d5h3.aspx))

Comment: This will definitely work, but you'll have to do an extra check for each property.  By setting BindingFlags.SetProperty you will only ever retrieve properties that contain setters.

Comment: I would recommend using the PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod and checking if it is null; the PropertyInfo.CanWrite method will return true if there is a private, protected, or internal set on the property.  It will only return false if there is actually no setter on the property.

Answer (score 25):

```
propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null
```