# Property Set Method not found, Exception System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#

i am trying to copy properties to update the supplier in my code

Here is my supplier update method

```
public bool UpdateSupplier(PurchaseOrderHeader header, string newSupplier)
    {
        try
        {
            var oldSupplier = GetSupplierForPoHeader(header);
            Reflection.CopyPropertyValues(oldSupplier, newSupplier);
            Console.WriteLine($"{oldSupplier} : {newSupplier}");
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is my method for updating the values.

```
public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination)
    {
        try
        {
            var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
            {
                if (destProperty.Name != sourceProperty.Name ||
                    !destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType) ||
                    destProperty.Name == "Id")
                    continue;

                destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, new object[] { }),
                    new object[] { });
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Inner Exception: "+e.InnerException?.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(@"Message: "+e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

I checked other stack overflow questions and it seems none of them are fixing my issue, i am fairly new to reflection so i have no idea how to go about fixing this myself.

Comment: In which line is the error thrown? Between the if and the break?

Comment: `var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();` You are getting all properties, not just properties with setters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390358/using-reflection-how-do-i-detect-properties-that-have-setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these:

- The property you try to set need to have a setter. (`PropertyInfo.CanSet`)
- is the setter private, you have to tell the SetValue method, that it should set it anyway using the `BindingFlags` (or use they code bellow).
- Is the property derived and the setter private, and you still want to set it, you need to get the property from the `DeclaringType`, because private members are not found on the derived class (but the property is because of a public getter) or use they code bellow.

If you want to access private setters, you may find this useful:

```
var setterMethod = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);
setterMethod.Invoke(instance, new [] { value });
```

Note that you also get Indexers as properties. They take an additional argument. You probably want to exclude them also (`!propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Any()`).

Comment: You was correct, i had a property that wasn't mapped, so i wasn't actually aware i was using it for anything, but refliction doesn't ignore the [NotMapped] Attributes, so now i hardcoded a fix, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can access the attributes yourself using reflection, then it's supported by your code. :-)

Comment: I think is "PropertyInfo.CanWrite"

Answer (score 2):

This error means that your property doesn't have any set method. You have few ways of fixing this but I'll point out only 2 of them :

1- Implement `set` method in your properties :

```
public <type> PropertyName
{
    get;
    set; /// <-- here 
}
```

2- Use this property's backing field:
Every property has it's own backing field which differs from implementation method. If you implemented your property as : `public <type> Name {get;set;}` then your backing field's name is `<Name >k__BackingField` which you can change as you like. To retrieve backing field use this code :

```
meObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public).Where(prop => prop.Name.EndsWith("__BackingField"));
```

This will return your backing field of autoproperty.

---

Making final conclusion to your problem. Do not use `GetProperties()` as properties always have some backing field. Use `GetFields()` instead because all that properties are doing is just modifying their backing field or returns ( almost ) constant value.

[Online example](http://rextester.com/MOIY41073)

Answer (score 0):

The `GetProperties()` method has an overload that takes BindingFlags to specify how the reflection search is conducted;

```
source.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Public) // ... & and other flags you need
```